# How can you model a complex type in multiple abstract dimensions?

Tags: types, functional-programming, f#, domain-driven-design, discriminated-union

### Background

I am trying to use the style of functional DDD laid out in "Domain Modeling Made Functional" by Scott Wlaschin. One particular point of interest to me is the concept of breaking apart a single type (in our case this will be a *Payment*) into separate types that more accurately represent the data available in the different "states" of the original type. In Scott's example on page 84 he separates an *Order* type into an *UnvalidatedOrder* type and a *ValidatedOrder* type. Thus you could describe an *Order* type as a union type as follows

```
type Order = 
  | UnvalidatedOrder of { ... }
  | ValidatedOrder of { ValidatedAt: DateTime; ... }
```

*I am using an F#-like pseudocode here for brevity*

This works well because the *Order* type here is only variant in "one dimension", that being the "Validation Dimension". So what if we have a type that varies in two "dimensions"?

### The Example of a Payment

Let's consider the example of a *Payment* model that has the following requirements:

#### Requirement 1) Status of a Payment

Payments must be in a valid state (*New*, *InProgress*, or *Complete*).
A *Payment* may be changed to be *InProgress* iff a *Payment* is *New*
A *Payment* may be changed to be *Complete* iff a *Payment* is *InProgress*

#### Requirement 2) Payment Result

*Payments* that are *Complete* must have a valid result (*Approved*, *Cancelled*, *Declined*, *Failed*)
An *Approved* *Payment* requires an *ApprovedAmount*
A *Cancelled*, *Declined*, or *Failed* *Payment* requires a *Reason*

#### Requirement 3) Payment information

All *Payments* must have a unique `Guid` to track them
All *Payments* must have a *RequestedAmount* on them

My attempt at modelling this looked as follows

```
type PaymentResult =
  | Approved of { ApprovedAmount: decimal }
  | Cancelled of { Reason: String; }
  | Declined of { Reason: String; }
  | Failed of { Reason: String; }

type PaymentStatus = 
  | New
  | InProgress of { StartedAt: DateTime; }
  | Complete of { 
      StartedAt: DateTime; 
      CompletedAt: DateTime; 
    }

type Payment = {
  Id: Guid;
  RequestedAmount: decimal;
  Status: PaymentStatus;
}

type StartPayment = (Status: PaymentStatus.New) (Now: DateTime) -> PaymentStatus.InProgress
type FinishPayment = (Status: PaymentStatus.InProgress) (Now: DateTime) (Result: PaymentResult) -> PaymentStatus.Complete
```

My concern about this attempt is that we are storing information about the *Payment* in the *PaymentStatus* type. In my understanding, the data that *PaymentStatus* contains should only be information about the *PaymentStatus*.

We can fix this problem by splitting the *Payment* type as Scott does and we get

```
type Payment =
  | NewPayment of { ... }
  | InProgressPayment of { StartedAt: DateTime; ... }
  | CompletedPayment of { 
      StartedAt: DateTime; 
      CompletedAt: DateTime; 
      Result: PaymentResult; 
      ... 
    }
```

This model seems to keep the data related to the *Payment* in *Payment* records.

Now what if we add the concept of being able to abandon a *Payment*, regardless of it's status.

If we were just modelling the abandoned *Payments* we would get

```
type Payment =
  | NonAbandonedPayment of { ... }
  | AbandonedPayment of { AbandonedAt: DateTime; ... }
```

However, in combining the two "dimensions", that of "Abandoned-ness" and "Status", I would have to create 6 separate types to represent all of the cases

```
type Payment =
  | NonAbanonedNewPayment
  | AbandonedNewPayment
  | NonAbandonedInProgressPayment
  | AbandonedInProgressPayment
  | NonAbandonedCompletePayment
  | AbandonedCompletePayment
```

This results in a cartesian product of the two "dimensions" of a *Payment*. This is already unwieldly and it is as simple a case as I can think of.

### The Question

How would you go about representing these multiple dimensions of a type, given the premise that all information relevant to a type should be stored inside that type?

My current best answer is to abandon the premise in the question and simply define a *PaymentStatus* type and a *AbandonedStatus* type are used as properties in the single *Payment* type as given in my initial attempt in the example.

```
type AbandonedStatus =
  | NotAbandoned
  | Abandoned

type PaymentStatus =
  | New
  | InProgress
  | Complete

type Payment = {
  Status: PaymentStatus;
  AbandonedStatus: AbandonedStatus
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're very close. All you need to do is model each dimension fully, and then combine them in a record type, like this:

```ml
type PaymentStatus =
  | New of { ... }
  | InProgress of { StartedAt: DateTime; ... }
  | Completed of { 
      StartedAt: DateTime; 
      CompletedAt: DateTime; 
      Result: PaymentResult; 
      ... 
    }

type PaymentAbandonment =
  | NonAbandoned of { ... }
  | Abandoned of { AbandonedAt: DateTime; ... }

type Payment =
  {
    Status : PaymentStatus
    Abandonment : PaymentAbandonment
  }
```

Since your final Payment type has 3x2=6 states, it should definitely be a product type (i.e. record), rather than a sum type (i.e. union). These are [algebraic data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type).